# Does this arrangement of objects leak?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, weak-references

I have two classes A and B. In A, I am creating an object of B, and in B I am accessing the back Button property of class A. In B, I have declared A as a weak reference variable. The code runs fine without any crash. However I am not sure if there is memory leak occurring in my implementation. Also, do I have to declare backButton as a weak reference in A ?

```
@interface A : UIViewController
{

    IBOutlet UIButton *backButton;
    B * cntrl;

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *backButton;

// Here is the implementation of A
@implementation A
@synthesize backButton;

// pushing to B
cntrl = [[B alloc]initWithNib:nil bundle:nil];
cntrl.parent = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:cntrl animated:YES];


@interface B:UIViewController
{
    A __weak *parent;
}

@implementation

-(void)method
{

parent.backButton.enable = NO;
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I can't think of a situation where a child would strong link its parent. Always use weak linking for this kind of relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your code is fine.
If you have any doubt, you can test your app with instruments.

Comment: what about releasing cntrl after pushing ??

Comment: I am using ARC, so I don't have to manually release the cntrl. IOS will do it for me.